# Fontsquirrel and webfont conversion

Tags: web-fonts

I've been trying to convert the font `M+ 2p` with fontsquirrel, and I have searched their website about the converter's limitations, but, no matter what I do, it seems their converter hangs on 0% conversion progress for this particular font.

Is there any other tool, similar to fontsquirrel, that I can use to convert these? If possible, with similar font optimizations...

Thanks in advance.

This font is free and available at http://mplus-fonts.sourceforge.jp/mplus-outline-fonts/download/index-en.html.

Comment: I'm aware that fontsquirrel has a couple similar fonts, already converted to webfont kits, namely `M+ 1c` and `M+ 1m`, and if i'm really unable to get `M+ 2p` converted, I might have to use one of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [FontPrep](http://fontprep.com/), a desktop client for Mac which converts the fonts for you. It also converts the font into Data URIs. I have been using it for a while and it works great.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This would definitely solve my problem, although I don't have access to a mac... I'll hold until I find a windows solution, if not, I'll accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: Well... I did find a solution for windows based systems, it's also available in perl so I assume it works on any OS... This solution however, is very similar, to the one Mr. Ram Ratan Maurya presented, so I am accepting his answer. You can check it out at: http://scripts.sil.org/FontUtils. Thanks again. \\//_